# Javascript Test - Verify if Authorization header is correct using axios

Tags: javascript, testing, mocking, sinon, axios

I'm using an axios interceptor to set the Authorization token in requests headers.

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + Auth.getToken()
  return config
})
```

How can i test if my requests are sent with correct token in header?

Ps.: I'm using Mocha + Chai

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [axios-mock-adapter](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter) to mock Axios, and get the request information from the config object in:

```
.reply((config) => {})
```

Example:

```
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter'

const axiosMock = new MockAdapter(axios)

axiosMock.onGet('https://api.com').reply((config) => {
    return [200, { requestHeaders: config.headers }]
});

const response = await axiosWrapper.get('https://api.com')
expect(response.data.requestHeaders['Authorization'] === 'AUTH_TOKEN')
```

To test if the *correct* token is in the header, an integration test would be more approriate. When the correct token is in the header, the API response should be different than when an incorrect token is sent with the request to the API.

Comment: Any way to do this without invading on `response.data`?

Comment: Just in case you are not using a custom axios instance (i.e axios.create) as per the axiosWrapper var and were unsure where this was coming from you can replace axiosWrapper with the default axios (i.e axiosWrapper.get('https://api.com') becomes axios.get('https://api.com')). Hope this helps anyone wondering where axiosWrapper was coming from in the answer!

Answer (score -2):

If would like to test your headers in the response you could do something like this:

```
    const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
    mock.onGet('/anon/getUser').reply(200, {/*response.data*/}, {'my-header-key': 'my-value' });
```

Comment: the *response.data is optional here

Comment: He wants to test the headers not to mock them.